# Mongoose insertMany() return callback is not a function error while passing options

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose **version 4.7.2** and need to insert a bulk amount of data into a collection without duplicates and validation errors as a **promise** .

Code :

```
  module.exports.addCustomers = function (customers) {
   return Customer.insertMany(customers,{ordered :false})
   }
```

While trying to insert the documents using insertMany() the following error occurred.

**TypeError: callback is not a function**

[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOqop.png)

There is no error when I remove  {ordered :false} from my code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a callback function so that when the function finishes processing, it can give back the results. See the documentation here

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.insertMany

Comment: I need it as a Promise()

Comment: have you added this code `const mongoose = require('mongoose'); mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;` ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be as follows:

```
module.exports.addCustomers = function (customers) {
   return Customer.insertMany(customers,{ordered :false}, function(err, res){
     if(err) { 
       //handle error here
     } else {
       //DO stuff if you got response
     }
 )}
```

Comment: Still getting the same error. I think this is a mongoose version-specific error.

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit odd. It should be able to work without the callback, if you process the response as a promise. You may try to execute the query inside your function:

```
module.exports.addCustomers = async function (customers) {
    const result = await Customer.insertMany(customers, {ordered: false})
    return result
}
```

I've tested that on mongoose `5.2.12`.